# Дублируются переменные в потоке

Tags: delphi, потоки-данных

Добрый день, есть 10 созданных потоков в процедуре потока запускается внешняя функция остановки потоков + вывода прогресс бара, но дело в том что при вызове функции я меняю переменную и запрещаю ей исполнятся еще 9 раз. Но ей хоть бы хны. Все равно исполняется 10 раз.

Функция:

```
var
  PRStop: boolean; //Огласим переменную

function TForm1.closemen:boolean;
begin
   if PRStop = false then begin
      PRStop := True;
      progressStop := 10;

      ProgressBar1.Visible := True;
      Label12.Visible := True;

      Timer1.Enabled := True;

      ProgressBar1.Max := progressStop;
      ProgressBar1.Position := progressStop;
      Application.ProcessMessages;

      Label12.Caption := 'Осталось: 10 сек.';
      Label12.Parent := Form1.ProgressBar1;
      Label12.Left   := (Form1.ProgressBar1.Width - Form1.Label12.Width) div 2;
      Label12.Top    := 6;
      Label12.Transparent := True;
   end;
end;

procedure Parser.Execute;
begin
  Form1.closemen;
end;
```

Не понимаю почему переменная PRStop не меняется на True. Я думаю что просто каждый поток ее дублирует. Если я прав то как сделать эту переменную одной для N-ного кол-ва потоков!?

**Спасибо!**

Comment: потому что нельзя так работать из потока с методами и переменными. RTFM Synchronize, CriticalSection.

Comment: Ну и как мне сделать быструю остановку всех потоков? Никак! Поэтому я хотел блокировать все кнопки и включать отсчет, после которого все потоки останавливались.

Comment: что значит "никак"? другие умеют, а у вас "никак". похоже вы просто не понимаете что такое потоки и как они должны взаимодействовать друг с другом.  
читайте документацию, смотрите примеры. по поводу вопроса начинающегося словами "ну и как..." видимо придется вам самому разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего переменная не успевает измениться. Смотри, ты вызываешь:

```
ShowMessage('Работаешь 10 раз? Сволочь!!!!');
```

вылазит окно, и в этот момент выполняется функция с другого потока.

Попробуй поменять местами:

```
function TForm1.closemen:boolean;
begin
   if PRStop = false then begin
      PRStop := True;
      ShowMessage('Работаешь 10 раз? Сволочь!!!!');
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Да  это работает, но я думал смогу этим сделать вывод прогресс бара, а он не выводится, обновил первый пост. Как сделать так что бы прогресс бар выводился и текст на него налегал... + Запустить таймер отсчета??